# Вывод данных из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Пишу простой модуль для Joomla для вывода ссылок, нужно вывести название и ссылку.

Файл модуля mod_seo_link.php

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';

$list = ModSeoLinkHelper::getList($params);

require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_seo_link');
```

Обработчик helper.php

```
    class ModSeoLinkHelper {

    public static function getList($params) {
        // Obtain a database connection
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
// Retrieve the shout
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select($db->quoteName(array('title', 'link')))
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__mod_seo_link'));//table name
// Prepare the query
        $db->setQuery($query);
// Load the row.
        $result = $db->loadResult();
// Return the Hello
        return $result;
    }

}
```

и выводит все это файл default.php

```
    defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>
<div class="seo_link">
    <?php
    foreach ($list as $key => $item) {?>
    <a href="<?php echo $item ->link; ?>"><?php echo $item -> title; ?></a>
   <?php }

   unset($item);?>
</div>
```

цикл не работает,подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил заменив в файле обработчика helper.php строку

```
  $result = $db->loadResult();
```

на

```
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```